# Need help with MOTD

Tags: python3, motd

I want to make a cool banner/motd display upon SSH which I have partially done. I decided to make the 'banner' part with Python as I have experience with a library called 'colorama' - colors text. When I run `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` it shows the color but when I log in it is just plain white, no coloring added.

I would like to have the color applied when it is displayed upon SSH login.

PS: I am new to the community so pls rip into me :D

**banner.py**

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore

init()

print(Fore.YELLOW + ''' __      ___      _               _ ''' + Fore.WHITE + '''    _____ _             _     ''')
print(Fore.YELLOW + ''' \ \    / (_)    | |             | |''' + Fore.WHITE + '''   / ____| |           | |    ''')
print(Fore.YELLOW + '''  \ \  / / _ _ __| |_ _   _  __ _| |''' + Fore.WHITE + '''  | (___ | |_ __ _  ___| | __ ''')
print(Fore.YELLOW + '''   \ \/ / | | '__| __| | | |/ _` | |''' + Fore.WHITE + '''   \___ \| __/ _` |/ __| |/ / ''')
print(Fore.YELLOW + '''    \  /  | | |  | |_| |_| | (_| | |''' + Fore.WHITE + '''   ____) | || (_| | (__|   <  ''')
print(Fore.YELLOW + '''     \/   |_|_|   \__|\__,_|\__,_|_|''' + Fore.WHITE + '''  |_____/ \__\__,_|\___|_|\_\ ''')
```

**00-header** - *file in /etc/update.motd.d - where Python should be executed*

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -r /etc/lsb-release ] && . /etc/lsb-release

if [ -z "$DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/lsb_release ]; then
        # Fall back to using the very slow lsb_release utility
        DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=$(lsb_release -s -d)
fi

python3 /etc/update-motd.d/banner.py
printf "\nRunning %s (%s %s %s)\n" "$DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION" "$(uname -o)" "$(uname -r)" "$(uname -m)"
```

Comment: As I see in [this response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/431783/285162), it is possible to change colors in motd. Add `export TERM=xterm-256color` right before `python3 /etc/update-motd.d/banner.py`

Comment: Gave it ago but doesn't seem to work. Very strange.